# How to write a query that returns columns from join tables (associated using custom class) that returns an ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event_type, :class_name => 'Keyword', :foreign_key => :event_type_id, optional: false
    belongs_to :promotion_type, :class_name => 'Keyword', :foreign_key => :promotion_type_id, optional: false    
end

class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events
end
```

I am attempting to write a query that returns columns form the joined table however I only seem to be able to create a working query if I use `Pluck` - which I do not wish to use as that ensures the query returns an array.  I need the query to return an ActiveRecord Relation.

Here is the query working using Pluck.  (Returns Array)

```
Event.joins(:event_type).pluck('event.id, event.name, keywords.name')
```

When I attempt to use Select the joined table column does not appear in the results.  (Returns ActiveRecord Relation which is what I need)

```
Event.joins(:event_type).select('event.id, event.name, keywords.name')
```

I'm obviously missing something simple but stuck.  Can anyone help?

Comment: `joins` doesn't add the rows from the _joined_ table to the result, it makes them available to be used in your query. If you're looking to get all of them, then try `as_json` or mapping your own output.

Comment: Try to use 'includes' instead of 'joins'. 
`Event.includes(:event_type).select('event.id, event.name, keywords.name')`

Comment: I ended up adjusting model associations - removing the custom class name.  Once I did this the query worked as I was expecting using the Select option.  Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adjusting my models in order to remove custom class.  Once I did this the query worked as I always expected it to do.

`Event.joins(:event_type).select('event.id, event.name, keywords.name')`

Case closed.